# filtering dataframe with multiple condition

Tags: r, filter

I need to update a spreadsheet with 1000 rows which has a problem.

I have two datasets:

df

```
CompanyID1      TMC1
ABC company     QBT
BCD company     G W TMC
jb hi fi        QBT
ABC company     GW TMC
FB Company     AMEX
LL company     AMEX
j k             QBT
k. l company    TP oil
1 to 1 lts      TP oil
2 in 1 pty ltd.  AMEX
```

df2

```
DRA CompanyID2          TMC2    Status
11  2 in 1 pty ltd.     AMEX    sent
12  1 to 1 lts          TP oil  produce
13  BCD company         ACE     sent
14  k. l company        TP oil  sent
15  jb hi fi             QBT    produce
16  ABC company          QBT    sent
17  j k                  QBT    sent
18  FB Company           AMEX   sent
19  facebook pty         QBT    sent
20  2 in 1 pty ltd.     AMEX    produce
```

What I am trying to achieve is first find `df$CompanyID1` value in  `df2$CompanyID2` and if there is a match then if its `df$TMC1` matches `df2$TMC2` and then it must have `df2$status=='sent'` then create a new column in `df$new` and return the `df2$DRA` value; if the `df2$status=='produce'` then `df$new` should have 'delete'

**Example**

"ABC company" from `df1$CompanyID1` exist in `df2$CompanyID2`. ABC company's `df$TMC1` matches `df2$TMC2` and the `df2$status=='sent'`. Therefore, `df$new <- 16`

I will greatly appreciate your help. This will save enormous time which I can use for other productive purpose. Thanks

dput(df1)

```
structure(list(Company.ID1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
9L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1 to 1 lts", "2 in 1 pty ltd.", 
"ABC company", "BCD company", "FB Company", "j k ", "jb hi fi", 
"k. l company", "LL company"), class = "factor"), TMC1 = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("AMEX", "G W TMC", 
"GW TMC", "QBT", "TP oil"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Company.ID1", 
"TMC1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

dput(df2)

```
structure(list(DRA = 11:20, Company.ID2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
4L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("1 to 1 lts", "2 in 1 pty ltd.", 
"ABC company", "BCD company", "facebook pty", "FB Company", "j k ", 
"jb hi fi", "k. l company"), class = "factor"), TMC2 = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("ACE", "AMEX", 
"QBT", "TP oil"), class = "factor"), Status = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("produce", "sent"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DRA", "Company.ID2", "TMC2", 
"Status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

## #

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df1))
        {
        if(df1$Company.ID1[i]==df2$Company.ID2[i] & df1$TMC1[i]==df2$TMC2[i] & df2$Status[i]=='sent')
                data1$new[i]<- 'sent'
}else{ data1$new<- 'delete'}
```

However there could be more than 1 company from `df1$Company.ID1` with same names in `df2$Company.ID2` and they could be in different rows as well.

My expected output would be following:

1. Matching company x name from `df1$Company.ID1` to  `df2$Company.ID2`
2. If it matches check company x's `data1$TMC1` matches `df2df2$TMC2`
3. If 1 & 2 is TRUE then check the status of company x from `df2$Status=='sent'`
4. If it is TRUE then create a new column df1$new and get the DRA number `df$DRA` and store it for that company x

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a merge and identify approach:

```
#Merge data on ID and TMC columns
m <- merge(df2, df, by.x=c("CompanyID2", "TMC2"),
      by.y=c("CompanyID1", "TMC1"))

#If "sent" use DRA, if not "delete"
m$Output <- ifelse(m$Status == "sent", as.character(m$DRA), "delete")

#Remove unnecessary columns
m[-(3:4)]
#   CompanyID2 TMC2 Output
# 1        ABC  QBT     16
# 2        BCD  ACE     13
# 3         jb  QBT delete
```

Comment: @pierre lafortune Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df2, df1, by = c("CompanyID2" = "CompanyID1", "TMC2" = "TMC1")) %>%
      mutate(Output = ifelse(Status == "sent", DRA, "delete"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("select df2.CompanyID2,df2.TMC2, df2.Status, df2.DRA as output 
              from df1 
              join df2 on df1.CompanyID1=df2.CompanyID2 and df1.TMC1=df2.TMC2")

res[res$Status=="produce",]$output <- "delete"

       # CompanyID2   TMC2  Status output
# 1     ABC company    QBT    sent     16
# 2        jb hi fi    QBT produce delete
# 3      FB Company   AMEX    sent     18
# 4            j k     QBT    sent     17
# 5    k. l company TP oil    sent     14
# 6      1 to 1 lts TP oil produce delete
# 7 2 in 1 pty ltd.   AMEX    sent     11
# 8 2 in 1 pty ltd.   AMEX produce delete
```

Comment: or perhaps this variation of the last line: `res[res$Status == "produce", "output"] <- "delete"`